# how to use getsupportactionbar() without extends actionbaractivity in android

Tags: android

I am new to android. In my project, I have extended youtubebaseactivity instead of actionbaractivity. I want to hide actionbar while playing a video. I can not use getsupportactionbar(). Please tell me how to use that or any other possibilities is there?